# JavaScript: How to download a file, then force a page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title mentions, I am trying to download a file which is served with associated mime type via PHP script given by href URL, then reload the same page, but can't quite figure it out, here's what I have so far:

```
<a id="viewAttachmentLink" href="/path/to/script.php?id=123">View Attachment</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    jquery('#viewAttachmentLink').bind('click', function() {
        if (myFunction()) {
            window.location.href = "jquery(this).attr('href')";
            setTimeout(location.reload(), 400);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

With this code, it will reload the page, but appears to not make the call to the PHP script.

Comment: What do you mean by download a file? Are you wanting to load the resource to execute something in the browser or download the file to the user's computer? Is it a typo the line setting href to a string?

Comment: A few oddities: 1. what is `myFunction()`? 2. it would be `window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');` 3. why do you need to `reload()` when you're already setting the href to something else?

Comment: @AndrewHubbs: Download the file, then reload the page.

Comment: @BrianCray: MyFunction is just a placeholder call indicating that I am making a call to another function which will return true/false. Didn't want to add all that code as it doesn't pertain to the question.

Comment: You should probably just navigate to the php page and add a "META REFRESH NAVIGATE" in the php file?

Comment: @HanletEscaño: Interesting, I'll check it out.

Comment: @BrianCray since window is the highest level global object, location would be resolved to window anyway.

Comment: @thescientist I understand that, I was just copying what he had and correcting the bad part (the piece after the =)

Comment: I was able to sort of resolve the situation by adding 'target=_new' to the link definition. Now when link is clicked the download will force open a new window where the remote php script will dictate header content, etc. The browser then downloads the file and closes the window, then the main window reloads. Going to leave this open if anyone has a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a file download and status update (through a header) like this:

```
<a id="downloadData">Download data...</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#downloadData').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/data',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
                var output = request.getResponseHeader('output');
                //refresh page here and use the output
                //console.log(output);
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                var url = '/data';
                a.href = url;
                a.click();
                //save file
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, I was able to get around the issue by adding a `target="_new"` attribute to the link. So when the link was clicked it would send the request to the remote php script to another window, which would control the headers and start downloading the file, and the original window would reload as needed.